# ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate padding with 'padding=True'

Tags: nlp, pytorch, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to evaluate `facebook/hubert-base-ls9601` Huggingface pre-trained model after fine-tuning on a private dataset.

I am using `facebook/hubert-base-ls9601` pre-trained model, and Wav2vec2 feature extractor, and pooling mode set to `mean`.

Here's the evaluation code:

```
test_dataset = load_dataset("csv", data_files={"test": "/content/drive/MyDrive/freelancing/test.csv"}, delimiter="\t")["test"]

def speech_file_to_array_fn(batch):
    speech_array, sampling_rate = torchaudio.load(batch["path"])
    resampler = torchaudio.transforms.Resample(sampling_rate, target_sampling_rate)
    speech = resampler(speech_array).squeeze().numpy()
    batch["speech"] = speech_array
    return batch


def predict(batch):
    features = feature_extractor(batch["speech"], sampling_rate=feature_extractor.sampling_rate, return_tensors="pt", padding=True)

    input_values = features.input_values.to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
        logits = model(input_values).logits 

    pred_ids = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1).detach().cpu().numpy()
    batch["predicted"] = pred_ids
    return batch

test_dataset = test_dataset.map(speech_file_to_array_fn)
result = test_dataset.map(predict, batched=True, batch_size=2)
```

On the last line of code, I encounter the following error block:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/feature_extraction_utils.py in convert_to_tensors(self, tensor_type)
    168                 if not is_tensor(value):
--> 169                     tensor = as_tensor(value)
    170 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,220683) into shape (2,)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

12 frames

<ipython-input-73-7bd88adad349> in <module>()
----> 1 result = test_dataset.map(predict, batched=True, batch_size=2)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in map(self, function, with_indices, with_rank, input_columns, batched, batch_size, drop_last_batch, remove_columns, keep_in_memory, load_from_cache_file, cache_file_name, writer_batch_size, features, disable_nullable, fn_kwargs, num_proc, suffix_template, new_fingerprint, desc)
   1970                 new_fingerprint=new_fingerprint,
   1971                 disable_tqdm=disable_tqdm,
-> 1972                 desc=desc,
   1973             )
   1974         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    517             self: "Dataset" = kwargs.pop("self")
    518         # apply actual function
--> 519         out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    520         datasets: List["Dataset"] = list(out.values()) if isinstance(out, dict) else [out]
    521         for dataset in datasets:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    484         }
    485         # apply actual function
--> 486         out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    487         datasets: List["Dataset"] = list(out.values()) if isinstance(out, dict) else [out]
    488         # re-apply format to the output

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/datasets/fingerprint.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    456             # Call actual function
    457 
--> 458             out = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    459 
    460             # Update fingerprint of in-place transforms + update in-place history of transforms

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in _map_single(self, function, with_indices, with_rank, input_columns, batched, batch_size, drop_last_batch, remove_columns, keep_in_memory, load_from_cache_file, cache_file_name, writer_batch_size, features, disable_nullable, fn_kwargs, new_fingerprint, rank, offset, disable_tqdm, desc, cache_only)
   2340                                 indices,
   2341                                 check_same_num_examples=len(input_dataset.list_indexes()) > 0,
-> 2342                                 offset=offset,
   2343                             )
   2344                         except NumExamplesMismatchError:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in apply_function_on_filtered_inputs(inputs, indices, check_same_num_examples, offset)
   2217             if with_rank:
   2218                 additional_args += (rank,)
-> 2219             processed_inputs = function(*fn_args, *additional_args, **fn_kwargs)
   2220             if update_data is None:
   2221                 # Check if the function returns updated examples

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in decorated(item, *args, **kwargs)
   1912                 )
   1913                 # Use the LazyDict internally, while mapping the function
-> 1914                 result = f(decorated_item, *args, **kwargs)
   1915                 # Return a standard dict
   1916                 return result.data if isinstance(result, LazyDict) else result

<ipython-input-71-6f845da29c00> in predict(batch)
     11 
     12 def predict(batch):
---> 13     features = feature_extractor(batch["speech"], sampling_rate=feature_extractor.sampling_rate, return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
     14 
     15     input_values = features.input_values.to(device)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/wav2vec2/feature_extraction_wav2vec2.py in __call__(self, raw_speech, padding, max_length, truncation, pad_to_multiple_of, return_attention_mask, return_tensors, sampling_rate, **kwargs)
    200             truncation=truncation,
    201             pad_to_multiple_of=pad_to_multiple_of,
--> 202             return_attention_mask=return_attention_mask,
    203         )
    204 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/feature_extraction_sequence_utils.py in pad(self, processed_features, padding, max_length, truncation, pad_to_multiple_of, return_attention_mask, return_tensors)
    230                 batch_outputs[key].append(value)
    231 
--> 232         return BatchFeature(batch_outputs, tensor_type=return_tensors)
    233 
    234     def _pad(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/feature_extraction_utils.py in __init__(self, data, tensor_type)
     78     def __init__(self, data: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None, tensor_type: Union[None, str, TensorType] = None):
     79         super().__init__(data)
---> 80         self.convert_to_tensors(tensor_type=tensor_type)
     81 
     82     def __getitem__(self, item: str) -> Union[Any]:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/feature_extraction_utils.py in convert_to_tensors(self, tensor_type)
    174                     raise ValueError("Unable to create tensor returning overflowing values of different lengths. ")
    175                 raise ValueError(
--> 176                     "Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate padding "
    177                     "with 'padding=True' to have batched tensors with the same length."
    178                 )

ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate padding with 'padding=True' to have batched tensors with the same length.
```

I am working on Google Colab. Those are the environment variables:

```
%env LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
%env LANG=C.UTF-8
%env TRANSFORMERS_CACHE=/content/cache
%env HF_DATASETS_CACHE=/content/cache
%env CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1
```

The padding is already activated in the `predict` function.

Can you please help me fix it?

Comment: Can you please add which model you are using (Wav2vec2?) and how you initialize it?

Comment: @cronoik I am using `facebook/hubert-base-ls9601` pre-trained model, and Wav2vec2 feature extractor, and pooling mode set to `mean`.